# Graphql-Java : Variable defined in Channel disappears (not available in DataFetcher)

Tags: java, graphql

I've built an example Graphql-Server Java App based on the https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-examples/tree/master/hibernate-example

My Channel layer is secured and each service method requires the Principal, so I've modified the Channel to add the Principal to each query:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/services/graphql", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Map<String, Object> graphql(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String query = (String) body.get("query");

    if (query == null) {
      query = "";
    }

    String operationName = (String) body.get("operationName");
    Map<String, Object> variables = (Map<String, Object>) body.get("variables");

    Map<String, Object> variableMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    if (variables != null)
      variableMap.putAll(variables);
    variableMap.put("principal", request.getUserPrincipal().getName());

    return executeGraphqlQuery(operationName, query, variableMap);
  }

  private Map<String, Object> executeGraphqlQuery(String operationName,
                                                  String query, Map<String, Object> variables) {
    ExecutionInput executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
            .query(query)
            .variables(variables)
            .operationName(operationName)
            .build();

    return graphql.execute(executionInput).toSpecification();
  }
```

I've debugged that plane and the `principal` value IS set.

The principal argument IS registered in the schema:

```
type Query {
    list(principal: String) : [ListElement]
}
```

However, then there comes the `DataFetcher`:

```
  private RuntimeWiring buildWiring() {
    return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
            .type(TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring("Query")
                    .dataFetcher("list", listFetcher)
            )
            .build();
  }
  

  private DataFetcher listFetcher = environment -> {
    String principal = environment.getArgument("principal");
    return listService.getAll(principal)
  };
```

And the principal argument is missing.

I've added for check an extra bogus variable and it IS propagated, only the variable I've added is missing, which is terribly confusing, because the original variable map is nowhere used.

Why is my variable swallowed between Channel and DataFetcher? Is there a hidden magic that wasn't mentioned in the tutorial?